# A polymorphic query is returning empty, when data is present

Tags: laravel

I currently have the following model: `Product`
in this model I have:

```
public function productDetails()
{
  return $this->morphMany(Productable::class, 'productable');
}
```

The DB record is as follows.  In Product I have:

```
id: 71,
product_name: 'this is a test',
description: 'some stuff',
```

I then have a model `Productable` with

```
public function productable()
{
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

The data in the database is:

```
62  71  App\Models\Media    1   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
63  71  App\Models\Media    7   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
64  71  App\Models\Media    8   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
65  71  App\Models\Media    9   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
66  71  App\Models\Attribute    3   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
67  71  App\Models\Coating  2   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
68  71  App\Models\ProductImage 9   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
```

Where 71 is the `product_id`

I then attempt to retrieve the data like so:

```
  $product = Product::find(71);
  dd($product->productDetails);
```

This returns an empty array.  I'm sure I'm missing something just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-to-many polymorphic relation is similar to a typical one-to-many relation; however, the child model can belong to more than one type of model using a single association. And that is what is happening, the records in the database belong to other models.

You are trying to obtain records that belong to other models. `Media`, `Attribute`, `Coating` and `ProductImage`. For this to work the records have to be assigned to the `Product` model.

Then the records in database should look something like the following:

```
62  71  App\Models\Product    1   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
63  71  App\Models\Product    7   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
64  71  App\Models\Product    8   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
65  71  App\Models\Product    9   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
66  71  App\Models\Product    3   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
67  71  App\Models\Product    2   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
68  71  App\Models\Product    9   2021-03-04 19:53:22 2021-03-04 19:53:22
```